# At what point is an instance of a class defined in an IOC container created

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, inversion-of-control, unity-container

I have recently become involved in a large project and I have very little experience of Unity and IOC/DI and I am looking for clarification on how instances are created when defined in a Unity container.

Given the following pieces of code;

//Unity Configuration

```
container.RegisterAsSingleton<IService, Service>();
```

//References in base controller class

```
private readonly IService _Service;

protected DefaultController(IService Service)
{
    _Service = Service;
}

protected string UseService(string id)
{
    return _Service.Method(id);
}
```

Do I need to initialise an instance using something similiar (in an MVC solution) to;

`_Service = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IService>()`;

or would an instance be created when the Service method is called first time?

```
_Service.Method(id);
```

I am trying to figure out the best place to put this code if required.

Comment: Is this for ASP.NET MVC? There is a [contribution project](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/) that allows you to wire Unity container to the automatic DI controller factory. You will have to use `Resolve` method at the DI root, later on you shall just pass this instance to all the children objects in the dependency graph. If you can use a contribution project, this is done automatically.

Comment: @oleksii Yes it is. Unfortunately, I am stuck with the framework that is currently in place and is based on the example I posted above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell for sure of course, but usually an MVC project using DI is wired up in a way that the DI container is not only used to create the IService instance, but also the DefaultController that depends on IService.

The MVC framework has extension points you can use to provide your own construction logic, for instance using a DI container like Unity or Windsor. If your project already uses DI, it is probably already setup that way.

So if everything is wired up correctly (DI container creates the controller, IService is registered to the DI container), the IService dependency is injected into the DefaultController constructor. You shouldn't have to do anything, IService should already be created when the controller method is called.

Comment: This certainly makes sense. From what I can see, there is no Unity configuration for the DefaultController, only the associated services. From this, I can only assume that I would need to resolve/create an instance of IService in the constructor of the DefaultController. Does that sound logical?

Comment: i can only make a guess here, but yes, usually you would have to register the controller with the container. But without detailed insight into the project and especially where Unity is actually used, this could be completely wrong. Maybe the controller is registered at some point during application startup and you just don't know where. At that point i'd recommend talking to someone with a bit more knowledge about the actual project, because manually calling the DI container to resolve a component is an anti pattern and should be avoided.